# initdb: initializing pg_authid ... FATAL: wrong number of index expressions

Tags: postgresql, startup

I'm new to PostgreSql.I'm trying to install PostgreSql in my system.My operating System is  Ubuntu,Below posted is my error

The database cluster will be initialized with locale en_US.UTF-8.
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to UTF8.

```
creating directory p01/pgsql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers/max_fsm_pages ... 24MB/153600
creating configuration files ... ok
creating template1 database in p01/pgsql/data/base/1 ... ok
initializing pg_authid ... FATAL:  wrong number of index expressions
STATEMENT:  CREATE TRIGGER pg_sync_pg_database   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON   

pg_database   FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE flatfile_update_trigger();

child process exited with exit code 1
initdb: removing data directory "p01/pgsql/data"
```

Help me out!!
 Thanks!

Comment: What's this pg_sync_pg_database and flatfile_update_trigger stuff? What version of the packages are you installing and is there anything else with them?

Comment: I think that the solution to your problem [here](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/17948.1365090217@sss.pgh.pa.us).

Comment: There's a woeful lack of data here. PostgreSQL version? How did you install it - packages/source, from where? Exact Ubuntu version? *What did you try before posting*? (given that the link Rhim posts is the **second google hit** for the error message)? That said, thanks for actually posting the relevant log output with exact error message and for even formatting it readably.

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same problem after compiling postgresql 8.1.4 with gcc 4.9.3.

The problem seems to be the way postgres uses to represent variable length arrays:

```
typedef struct
{
    int32       size;           /* these fields must match ArrayType! */
    int         ndim;
    int         flags;
    Oid         elemtype;
    int         dim1;
    int         lbound1;
    int2        values[1];      /* VARIABLE LENGTH ARRAY */
} int2vector;                   /* VARIABLE LENGTH STRUCT */
```

In some cases, for loops accessing 'values', GCC assumes that they will do one iteration at most. Loops like the one below (extracted from postgres's source code):

```
ii->ii_NumIndexAttrs = numKeys;
for (i = 0; i < numKeys; i++)
    ii->ii_KeyAttrNumbers[i] = indexStruct->indkey.values[i];
```

might end up being reduced to something like:

```
ii->ii_NumIndexAttrs = numKeys;
if (numKeys)
    ii->ii_KeyAttrNumbers[0] = indexStruct->indkey.values[0];
```

as deduced by looking at the assembler generated for it:

```
.L161:
    testl   %r12d, %r12d
    movl    %r12d, 4(%rbx)
    jle .L162
    movzwl  40(%r13), %eax
    movw    %ax, 8(%rbx)
.L162:
```

The problem went away after re-compiling postgres with that optimization disabled by using -fno-aggressive-loop-optimizations.

Comment: Newer versions of postgres use values[], if supported by the compiler, instead of values[1].

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem while building the centos 5 version of postgresql (8.2) for centos 7 (3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64.)

I wasn't able to make it work with gcc-4.8.3 using the CFLAGS="-O1" trick, but switching to clang (3.4.2) as the compiler (CC=clang) did work for me (and it worked at the default -O2 optimization level.)

Comment: This worked with Ubuntu 18.04 and PostgreSQL 8.4.22

Answer (score 4):

@Rhim appears to be correct - [you've hit what was assumed to be a compiler bug](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/17948.1365090217@sss.pgh.pa.us). You might want to update to the latest gcc packages then `make clean`, re-run `configure` with `CFLAGS="-O1"` as an argument, and then re-compile.

BTW, this suggests that you are compiling PostgreSQL 8.4 or older as `pg_sync_pg_database` doesn't appear in 9.0 or newer. You must also be compiling on a newer host. As PostgreSQL 8.4 will soon be end-of-life and unsupported, this is probably not a good idea.

It also suggests you've compiled your own version rather than using packages. You should use http://apt.postgresql.org/ rather than compiling your own unless you have a good specific reason.

Answer (score 3):

I ran in the same problem.
I have a production database in release 9.1 of Postgres and i must reinstall it on a new host.
I’m trying this on a Centos8 and a Debian11
gcc version 8.5.0

I used the CFLAGS environment variable :

```
export CFLAGS=-fno-aggressive-loop-optimizations
```

Others -O1 or clang didn’t work at all.
Then, everything worked perfect :

```
./configure --enable-debug  --enable-depend --prefix=$PG_HOME
gmake -j 5 world 
gmake check
```

No more errors