# Compiling Postgresql disable "fno-aggressive-loop-optimizations"?

Tags: c, postgresql, gcc

I'm trying to compilation and install PostgreSQL in my system. My operating System is Debian 9 gcc-4.9 Below posted is my error

> ```
> The database cluster will be initialized with locale en_US.UTF-8. The default database encoding has accordingly been set to UTF8.
>
> creating directory p01/pgsql/data ... ok
> creating subdirectories ... ok
> selecting default max_connections ... 100
> selecting default shared_buffers/max_fsm_pages ... 24MB/153600
> creating configuration files ... ok
> creating template1 database in p01/pgsql/data/base/1 ... ok
> initializing pg_authid ... FATAL:  wrong number of index expressions
> STATEMENT:  CREATE TRIGGER pg_sync_pg_database   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON   
>
> pg_database   FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE flatfile_update_trigger();
>
> child process exited with exit code 1
> initdb: removing data directory "p01/pgsql/data"
> ```

---

In another post, a user suggests to disable the "fno-aggressive-loop-optimizations". But how can I disable this? It is a parameter in ./configure when compiling the fonts.  See below the suggestion:

## [initdb: initializing pg_authid ... FATAL: wrong number of index expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583549/initdb-initializing-pg-authid-fatal-wrong-number-of-index-expressions/41412048#41412048)

> I ran into the same problem after compiling postgresql 8.1.4 with gcc 4.9.3.
>   The problem seems to be the way postgres uses to represent variable length arrays:
>
> ```
> typedef struct
> {
>     int32       size;           /* these fields must match ArrayType! */
>     int         ndim;
>     int         flags;
>     Oid         elemtype;
>     int         dim1;
>     int         lbound1;
>     int2        values[1];      /* VARIABLE LENGTH ARRAY */
> } int2vector;                   /* VARIABLE LENGTH STRUCT */
> ```
>
> In some cases, for loops accessing 'values', GCC assumes that they will do one iteration at most. Loops like the one below (extracted from postgres's source code):
>
> ```
> ii->ii_NumIndexAttrs = numKeys;
> for (i = 0; i < numKeys; i++)
>     ii->ii_KeyAttrNumbers[i] = indexStruct->indkey.values[i];
> ```
>
> might end up being reduced to something like:
>
> ```
> ii->ii_NumIndexAttrs = numKeys;
> if (numKeys)
>     ii->ii_KeyAttrNumbers[0] = indexStruct->indkey.values[0];
> ```
>
> as deduced by looking at the assembler generated for it:
>
> ```
> .L161:
>     testl   %r12d, %r12d
>     movl    %r12d, 4(%rbx)
>     jle .L162
>     movzwl  40(%r13), %eax
>     movw    %ax, 8(%rbx)
> .L162:
> ```
>
> The problem went away after re-compiling postgres with that optimization disabled by using -fno-aggressive-loop-optimizations.

Comment: Using `int2 values[1];` is an example of the 'struct hack'.  The standard-conforming way to write that is `int values[];`, making it into a flexible array member (FAM).  The compiler shouldn't optimize accesses to a FAM in the way you appear to be claiming it does.  I note that GCC 4.9.3 is old — the current version is 6.3.0 (unless there's been a release since then that I haven't noticed yet).  Maybe you should be using a newer compiler.

Comment: The code shown definitely has undefined behavior, and the optimization gcc is making is valid. Is there possibly a newer version of the software with the bug fixed?

Comment: PostgreSQL 8.1.4 is fairly old (it appears to be from 2006); the current version appears to be 9.6.1.  Why are you using decade-old software?  (GCC 4.9 appears to be from 2015, which is more recent than I expected. GCC has moved more rapidly of late than it had done in times past.  That said, GCC 5 and 6 have both been released since 4.9, and 4.9.4 is the last release in the 4.9.x family.)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the tips... I was able to solve the problem.

Here's the solution if someone has this problem.

To compile PostgreSQL 9.0.1 sources using GCC-4.9, I used the following directive in postgresql source:

```
./configure -prefix=/opt/postgres9.0 CFLAGS="-Wno-aggressive-loop-optimizations"
```

Wno-aggressive-looop-optiimizations disables aggressive GCCs Optimization, avoiding the error reported in previous message and in discussion-List pgsql-general ->
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAOD%3DoQ-kq3Eg5SOvRYOVxDuqibVWC8R0wEivPsMGcyzZY-nfzA%40mail.gmail.com

I hope the removal of "GCCs aggressive loop optimization" does not cause any errors of any kind in the DBMS.